# Apache - Check which virtual host routes a response

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

Was wondering if there was a way to see which virtual host entry is used for routing a request?  Is there some way to add the name of the virtual host file being used for the request to the `access.log` file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `LogFormat` directive can take a `%v` placeholder which does exactly what you want.

The `LogFormat` options are documented here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/logs.html#virtualhost

Answer (score 2):

I find the `Host:` header to be very useful as well, add this to your `LogFormat` directive:

```
%{Host}i
```

Comment: They return different values, so depending on your scenario you may want both. %v returns the Servername of the vhost the request landed on.